# Windows 10 recently makes a beeping sound and the mouse slows down

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have a odd problem:

For a while I was on Windows 11, and then it crashed, and essentially went into a reboot loop. I went back to Windows 10. And now, every so often, the computer makes a set of beeps or tones, and the mouse and UI just lag to hell and back. It happens mostly with Chrome. I'm using a Elocom trackball,

- 16 gigs of ram (ddr4)
- 1 500 gig drive just for windows
- 1 3tb drive for apps
- geforce 1660

I do have ds4 windows installed but not running. Googled it and I think someone on reddit had a similar problem having to do with xfce.
Where should I even start for to fix the issue?
Edit:
It's this bug: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/gvf01d/dualshock_4_issue_creates_mouse_lag_and_beeping/fsoez3s/

Comment: I think that "Elocom" should have been "Elecom", so try to install the [ELECOM Mouse Assistant](https://www.elecom.co.jp/global/download-list/utility/mouse_assistant/win/).

Comment: Do you know if something like the built in event viewer or usbdeview might show when and why it's happening to. I have external USB drive, and offten a playstation controller. Just thinking it (might) be possible that's to many USB things. But I can't imagine why.

Comment: It's always a good idea to look for information in the Event Viewer. Two USB devices are OK, but too many may cause power problems, although the problems in such a case usually involve one device not working at all.

Comment: 700 power warnings. and 200 WMI and device setup errors.  So is that meaning to many things chonked in and it's like: i just can't?  I don't know what to look for if it's a PSU issue.

Comment: It can also be a motherboard problem. Perhaps a repair-shop is best.

Comment: Yesterday I unplugged the PS4 controller from the computer. No more beeps. I am going to go out on a limb.  The controller was one to many things plugged in.  I'd also guess this bug https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/gvf01d/dualshock_4_issue_creates_mouse_lag_and_beeping/fsoez3s/

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the problem was too many USB devices that demand too much
power from the computer.

The sign of the problem were errors in the Event Viewer pertaining to
power and device setup errors.

A temporary solution was to disconnect one device, in this case
the PS4 controller. A permanent solution would be to buy a self-powered
USB hub that is in effect not limited by power supply.

Comment: Thanks! any suggested brands for a hub?

Comment: Anything with enough good notes on Amazon.

Comment: This is not even remotely close to the right answer.

Comment: @Aashishkebab: What makes you say that, in spite of the experience of the poster?

Comment: @harrymc it's anecdotal happenstance, but the statement doesn't actually make any sense from a technical standpoint. I've had this happen on Bluetooth mice, which instantly disproves it.

Comment: @Aashishkebab: A Bluetooth mouse has a USB dongle, so what does it disprove? And how do you know that your problem was the same as the poster's?